# Don't run a cucumber feature if a element on the page is not available but exit without failing

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I want to check a page for an element before I start running the feature file for it (It's an element that periodically appears with an event so I only want to run the feature if its present).

The approach I wanted to use was a tagged before hook to see if the element was present and if it wasn't just don't run the feature but exit without 'failing' the step just exit with a message. I tried variants on the below but 
1. If I don't have a rescue clause it obviously fails the scenario when the element isn't present
2. If I do have the rescue clause it handles it and passes moving onto the features which will then fail as the event isn't available.

Is there a way to halt running the feature file if the rescue clause is invoked without the 'fail'?

`Before('@event') do
  begin
    find('.event').visible?
 rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
    puts 'THE EVENT IS NOT ON'
  end
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `find` if you want to make a decision based on existence. Instead you should be using the predicate methods provided by Capybara (has_selector?, has_css?, has_xpath?, etc) so you don't have to rescue exceptions.

The other thing to know is the Cucumber `skip_this_sceanrio` method, which means you should end up with something like

```
Before('@event') do
  # visit '/some_page'   # May not be needed if you have another `Before` already visiting the needed page
  skip_this_scenario('Skipping due to missing event') unless page.has_css?('.event')
end
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, behaves exactly as I wanted